# jms/di-extra-bundle Call to a member function has() on null

Tags: php, symfony

U use Symfony 3.3.10 and php 7.1. I install `"jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.7.0"` and after that have error

```
Call to a member function has() on null
vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php
```

line 356

my action

```
    public function getAdminQuestionAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{
    try {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine();
```

after when I called `getDoctrine` I have exception 
this is path where I got exception

`vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php`

```
    /**
 * Shortcut to return the Doctrine Registry service.
 *
 * @return Registry
 *
 * @throws \LogicException If DoctrineBundle is not available
 */
protected function getDoctrine()
{
    if (!$this->container->has('doctrine')) {
        throw new \LogicException('The DoctrineBundle is not registered in your application.');
    }

    return $this->container->get('doctrine');
}
```

I think problem with container after installed  `jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.7.0`

Comment: From the limited info presented I'm going to say that in your second code block.. there is no container, which is why it comes up as null

Comment: Your controller is being instantiated without the container being injected.  Are you new'ing it yourself?  If not then maybe show the route.  Not really familiar with the di extra bundle.  Would not think it would impact controller creation.

Comment: no, second block from `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php line 356

`

Comment: I have just action where I just get entity manager `$em = $this->getDoctrine();` and then logic. Without `jms/di-extra-bundle` everything works

Comment: Sort of looks like the bundle is trying to define the controllers as services though the documentation seems confusing at best.  Seems very strange that this sort of problem would not be documented.  In any event, add the DI annotations to inject the container into your controller.

Comment: Might also just be a version mismatch.  I created a fresh 3.3.16 project and used "composer require jms/di-extra-bundle".  All seems to work well.  Ended up with version 1.9.1.  Maybe try a simple composer update and see what happens.

Comment: It's not helped, I removed vendor and run composer update. `Symfony 3.3.10`, `"jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.9.1"`

Comment: I change `"symfony/symfony": "~3.4",` `"jms/di-extra-bundle": "~1.9"` and still have a problem when get some service from container